# What does "hydration mismatch" mean in React or Vue?

Tags: html, reactjs, vue.js, web, dom

While using both Vue and React, I regularly stumble upon so-called "hydration mismatches".

What does it mean?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate

Answer (score -1):

**Note: hydrate has been replaced with hydrateRoot in React 18. **

Same as render(), but is used to hydrate a container whose HTML contents were rendered by ReactDOMServer

[Official Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-client.html#hydrateroot)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31625220)